# Displaying image in Ireports using PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports, ireport

I am trying to load image from PostgreSQL database into jaspersoft ireports(4.0) but I am receiving an error.

In PostgreSQL image is stored as bytea object. In ireports I have changed the property of image field to `java.io.InputStream`.

After placing the image in report following properties were set:

Expression class: `java.io.InputStream` 
Image expression: `image field`

I also tried [this](http://ireport-tutorial.blogspot.com/2008/11/show-blob-image-in-ireport.html) tutorial to show blob images in ireport.

Following error is displayed:

```
Error filling print... Image read failed. 
Setting up the file resolver... 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Image read failed. 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRJdk14ImageReader.readImage(JRJdk14ImageReader.java:73) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader.loadImage(JRImageLoader.java:245) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRImageRenderer.getImage(JRImageRenderer.java:476) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRImageRenderer.getDimension(JRImageRenderer.java:512) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.fitImage(JRFillImage.java:1251) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.prepare(JRFillImage.java:1173) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:329) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:419) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:378) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2038) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:760) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:270) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:247) 
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:877) 
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572) 
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997) 
Print not filled. Try to use an EmptyDataSource...
```

Comment: Can you post the code and report's template?

Comment: i am using ireports professional edition I have created a table in postgres with following columns log -double lat -double image-bytea Template - blank A4 template Then after placing the image report element from palette on report configured the image expression and expression class(java.io.InputStream) After running the report error message is displayed."Error displaying report page.See console for details'. errors i have posted above in the question.But when i remove the image element from report it works fine

Comment: Can you post image expression?

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL the `bytea` type is not a BLOB, and you can't use a stream.  In SQL standard terms it is a byte string.  It should be loaded to a byte array in Java.

If you want to use BLOB techniques in PostgreSQL you must use the *large objects* feature.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/largeobjects.html

Answer (score 2):

spending nearly one day, finally found the solution;

1. in sql query `select convert(your_image,'base64') as img from yourtable`
2. set image expression class to `java.io.InputStream`
3. in image expression `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader.getInstance(new SimpleJasperReportsContext()).loadAwtImageFromBytes(javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary($F{img}))`

**EDIT:**

My Postgresql version is : **9.4**,

Thanks to FiruzzZ he stated that **in postgresql 9.1** instead of convert function, encode(bytea,'base64') is available.

Comment: convert (bytea, string) doesn't work, the function is unknown for Postgres 9.1. I used encode(bytea,'base64') and worked

Answer (score 1):

Displaying Image from blob (postgresql) to Image in *iReport*

In Postgresql image is stored as blob-oid
 
*Code inside ReportController*

1. fetch that oid string from database convert it into byte
2. convert byte array value in ***InputStream*** value
3. map it to the parameter that will be used inside *iReport*
4. take one Image element change its type to ***java.io.InputStream***
5. Create one parameter of type ***java.io.InputStream*** (use the same name as mapped inside  ***ReportController***)
6. Now Build project and Run