# How to insert images from database?

Tags: mysql, database, image, jasper-reports

I want insert images from database in details band in my report in *Jaspersoft Studio*.
The JPG-images are saved in MySQL in the field ***imgdata*** of type *longblob*.
I`v tried to put this expressions in Image element:

1. `$F{imgdata}`
2. `MyUtil.getInputStream($F{imgdata})`

In the first case I get this error:

```java
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unknown image source class [B
```

... and in second case this error:

```java
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error
evaluating expression :  Source text :
MyUtil.getInputStream($F{imgdata})
```

My question:
How to insert images from database into *JasperReports*'s report?

Comment: May be [Displaying image in Ireports using PostgreSql](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8430313/876298) post help you

Comment: What is the type of `imgdata` field (in your *jrxml* file)?

Answer (score 10):

Open the XML view of .jrxml file.
Then find code similar to this

```
<field name="image" class="java.lang.Object"/>  
/* "image" must be replaced by your actual field name */
```

and change it to

```
<field name="image" class="java.io.InputStream"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems that I solved the issue myself.

Here are the steps I`v done:

1) The expression for the Image report field should be: **$F{imgdata}**

(Note: *imgdata* is name of the database field where image data is stored)

2) Open the "Dataset and Query Dialog" of your report and change the **Class Type** of the *imgdata* field from java.lang.Object to **java.io.InputStream** (<strike>see the screenshot</strike> ---  sorry I dont have enough reputation points to post images). Close the dialog.

3) Generate your report by switching to Preview-Tab. Now you should see the images in your report.

Comment: you save my life after 8 years.. thanks