# How to load image from Database using iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Currently I am working on *iReport*, using *MySql DB*.

I am saving the image as a String id using servlet, not exactly the image name (like helal.JPG). But i cannot rendered this as a image on *iReport*.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

For image 200 x 300 use `<imageExpression>` with String parameter.

E.g.

```
<parameter name="IMG_PATH" class="java.lang.String"></parameter>

...

<image ...>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="300"/>
    <imageExpression class="java.lang.String">
        <![CDATA[$P{IMG_PATH}]]>
    </imageExpression>
</image>
```

See also http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/images/index.html

Comment: So basically here you need to query the database for image path.

Comment: hi Michal,Thanks for your reply, but it does not work. i am using this

`<image scaleImage="FillFrame" onErrorType="Icon">
     <reportElement uuid="30376687-d88e-42b3-b279-fcfcce31eef0" x="0" y="249" width="102" height="36"/>
     <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{employeeSignature}]]></imageExpression>
    </image> 
`

Comment: here employeeSignature is my image value, which saved in DB as a Id like 4028b21240c34f360140c352f84e0004

Comment: I am using Oracle but i have to make the image a **java.io.InputStream** to make this work

Comment: Did you try to adjust imageExpression's class e.g. `<imageExpression class="java.io.InputStream">` ... (or whichever "class" is suitable)?

Comment: hi Michal, I have already used this, also used java.awt.Image class

Comment: What is the type of image? The above should work for JPG, PNG, GIF. Is it any different?

Comment: Maybe try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833031/jaspersoft-studio-report-how-to-insert-images-from-database or http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/514052/showing-image-database

Comment: hi MikeNoland and Michal, i think u guess my image is stored on DB as image format(like imageName.JPG, PNG etc), but it stored on My DB as a String id and i m  trying to rendered it by query that concat with servletRepository+id

Comment: Options are: 1. store image as BLOB, 2. introduce server call to actually return image (based on given string id). 

What is your structure of the images table?