# Getting Unable to get value for field 'logo' of class 'java.awt.Image' for JasperReports report

Tags: java, mysql, image, jasper-reports

I am new to Jasper Reports and i have to print a form with an image. I am using NetBeans. I have a main report with subreports. In one of the subreports there is an image logo which comes from MySql 5 database, stored as a blob. I receive this error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unable to get value for field 'logo' of class 'java.awt.Image'
```

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myclass</groupId>
    <artifactId>ReportTool</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>ReportTool</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>com.myclass.MainApp</mainClass>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <name>SomeName</name>
    </organization>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.8.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <vendor>myvedor</vendor>
                    <mainClass>com.myclass.MainApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-shade-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Here is my query string in the subreport jrxml:

```
<queryString language="SQL">
    <![CDATA[SELECT d.logo FROM doc d WHERE d.TITLE = 'logo']]>
</queryString>
```

And the image expression:

```
        <image>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="111" height="100" uuid="2ef1a6a2-a019-4969-9c44-75f8f242ecdb"/>
            <box padding="0"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{logo}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
```

Fields:

```
<field name="logo" class="java.awt.Image"/>
```

There is no Java code to handle the image, it should happen out of the box.

I have already tried the advice from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329842/show-image-from-database-getting-net-sf-jasperreports-engine-jrexception-image)

I changed the type to java.io.InputStream and it didn`t throw the error anymore but when the printing form opens, there is an error that the image cannot be read

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Image read failed.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.PrintDrawVisitor.visit(PrintDrawVisitor.java:196)
```

So I don`t think that this is the right solution for me.

Can someone help in solving this issue please?

UPDATE: I downloaded JasperSoft Studio and created the database connection. I get the same error there when I open the report. So it is not the java code but something else.

Comment: Did you try to debug? It is the simplest way to understand what is wrong

Comment: yes, I tried but it didn`t help. also, the source code where the error happens is the external jasper code.