# Images according to parameters

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new with iReport and I have a problem with images. I have a parameter `call id` and I want that images change according to this parameter. Those images are stored in a folder, not in a server.

How can I do that by entering the path (which is a field of a table in database) automatically select the image automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert images from database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833031/how-to-insert-images-from-database)

Comment: But i am not using java, just sql

Comment: You have template and you can apply approach described at post (duplicate link). There are a lot of similar posts at SO

Comment: so what should i do? write in that post?

Comment: Try solutions from this post. `write in that post?` - If you have an answer, yes. In other cases - no

Comment: I have created in database a new field call "path" where the path of the image is. Then i put this field on my report. My question is this way to do it is correct or i have to create a variable or a parameter?

Comment: Yes, you can use field (or variable). If the path is constant you can use parameter