# Insert image from PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, groovy, jasper-reports, classpath, bytea

I am using *iReport 5.0* and I am trying to insert picture from database.

The picture is stored in *PostgreSQL* in a *bytea* type field

I already tried [solution](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/514052/showing-image-database), but it does not work

If I use `JRImageLoader.loadImage((byte[])$F{slike})` in image expression I get an error:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: JRImageLoader for class: report_slika_1381233045022_689567
```

I also following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430313/displaying-image-in-ireports-using-postgresql), but it does not give me any results

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to use the *Java* language in report? Did you add *JRImageLoader* to classpath?

Comment: in Jasper report properties I added net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader if that is the deal, but it still wont print the picture

Comment: Would you try to map the field as java.io.InputStream

Answer (score 1):

In your report properties, set language set Java instead Groovy.

Add the following imports

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader