# Working with images from Postgresql to Ireport 5.5.0

Tags: image, postgresql, jasper-reports

I am working in Ireport 5.5.0 using Postgresql 9.1. I have a image field of type bytea. I want to print this field in IReport i have been searching over google from last two days but i couldn't find any solution.
I have tried every possible option in my mind but no success.
Kindly help me i stuck in this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert images from database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833031/how-to-insert-images-from-database) & [Displaying image in Ireports using PostgreSql](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8430313/876298)

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39320863/59087

Answer (score 0):

You can instead have a VARCHAR field where u just specify a path and then use that path to display the image that you want, the way you can do this depends on which programming langueage you are using.